# How can I convert logline timestamps to a different time zone?

Tags: shell, timestamps

I have some logs with a timestamp at the beginning of each line (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`). The timestamps are UTC time, but often I want to know when something happened in my local time. I can convert in my head, but it's an effort.

Usually I'm piping the logs to grep to pick out what I need. Is there something I can pipe through to convert timestamps from one timezone to another, while leaving the rest of the line intact?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a horrible innefficient solution in awk....

```
{
        cmd="date -d \"" $1 " " $2 " UTC\" \"+%F %H:%M:%S %Z\"";
        cmd | getline u
        $1="";
        $2="";
        print u $0;
}
```

Personally I'd write something in a more conventional programming language which supports strtotime()

Comment: With _GNU_ awk, and some minor editing with gsub or gensub, you can use [mktime from utc then strftime to local](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)